# How to make Windows 11 menu bar active item visible

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, windows-11, systemmenu

In Windows 11, Visual FoxPro 9 and applications created by it active system menu item background is almost
invisible.
It is difficult to distinquish active menu bar from others.

To reproduce:

1. Run Foxpro 9 in Windows 11
2. Press Alt key
3. Press right arrow key 4 times

Selected item, Program backgound is almost invisible:

[image]
How to fix it ?

Visual Styles are disabled in Foxpro.

I tried enable them

```
SYS(2700,1)
```

Tried to change off screen bitmap composition

```
SYS(602,0)
```

Also tried to change windows 11 color scheme but problem persists.

Comment: The Visual FoxPro menus are what are known as 'owner drawn' in Windows terms. Also the help states that the colours for them are taken from the Windows Control Panel and can't be changed by the application. So I think the situation here is that you can only change them via Windows, but Windows 11 doesn't provide a mechanism to do that. Perils of using unsupported software I suppose.

Comment: Mayba there is some registry or compatibility setting this allows to set it like it was in Windows 10  ?

Comment: If there was a Win 10 registry change that worked then it should work in Windows 11, which is really just a UI overhaul. There's a tool called SMACC (and various similar ones, but that one is free and has GitHub source) - that might work.

Comment: In Windows 10 and earlier it worked without any registry changes.